# Using GIT and TFS together

Tags: git, tfs

I'm having fun with an open source project available here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/dolserver/code/
That's the repository for an mmorpg server emulator and I'm making a custom server for my own.

The problem is that I need to update the repository in order to get/push updates, BUT there is a particular folder (GameServerScripts) which contains only scripts specifically made for my own server that must not be overwritten and must be saved in Tfs.

At the moment, I have a Tfs solution with my own repository and a folder on the desktop that I keep updated using Tortoise with the official repository.
That means that every time I need to check the official repository, look for changes in the tortoise history and copy and replace those files into my own repository and push them.

I'm looking for a better way to handle those changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you main repo is Git managed and you want to keep a TFS Version Control in sync. Best way is to use [git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/).