# Using Git and TFS together on common project

Tags: git, tfs

I work in a TFS shop.  That is, all our code, all our builds, everything is managed in TFS.

I work offsite, developing on multiple independent machines, on networks that are not connected to our main development network.

To this end, I have started using Git to manage my work between these multiple machines, and then push/sync things up to the TFS repository when necessary.

I started out, by just creating a git repository in my TFS workspace, and that just works.

BUT, this doesn't work with a couple peers who have similar workflows, who'd like to share my git repository.

I have seen this nearly identically worded question title:
[Using GIT and TFS together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286247/using-git-and-tfs-together) 
The main answer points to a tool: [git-tf](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf) that is EOL, which may have been what I wanted, but I'm not interested in an EOL tool.

I've seen this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2017/mar-29-team-services#import-repositories-from-tfvc-to-git
But I don't want to change the TFS repository to a GIT repository.  I want them to co-mingle.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If they want to share _your_ repo (assuming they want to work git-only), why don't you set up a **git** repo on a common location that all the developers can see and then you (and the other developers) push/pull-from there?

Comment: @eftshift0 No issue in sharing GIT between coworkers.  Issue is getting a coworker, able to push up from GIT to the TFS repository.  How does one do that?

Comment: You could be the bridge, I guess.

Comment: Use https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866832/whats-the-difference-between-git-tf-and-git-tfs

Comment: @Philippe, any reason that you didn't post that as an answer?  Seems like one to me.

Comment: "TFS" isn't a version control system. It's a platform that supports Git repos and TFVC repos. You can push your Git repo to TFS.

Comment: @John It was a quick answer, that's why. But I took the time to did it.

Comment: @John git-tfs change TFS repository to a GIT repository, you mentions you don't want it, so how it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want to use `git-tf` because it is no more supported, you can still use its alternative [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) which bring [some advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866832/whats-the-difference-between-git-tf-and-git-tfs)